# The functional equation $\big(1 + yf(x)\big)\big(1 - yf(x + y)\big) = 1$ for $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Functional equation from USAMO 2010 preparation session:

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ such that
> $\big(1 + yf(x)\big)\big(1 - yf(x + y)\big) = 1$
> for all $x, y \in \mathbb R^+$, where $\mathbb R^+$ is a set of all positive real numbers.

Well I don't really see what we can do. I mean I could have plugged in some numbers but the best one ($0$) which could have caused simplifications is out of reach and so are the negative numbers. Maybe if we could take two cases:

1. Both factors are equal to $\pm 1$.
2. The factors are reciprocals of each other.

In the first case $+1$ in fact is only possible when $f(x)=0$ $ \forall x$, which isn't possible as $0$ isnt in the codomain. For $-1$ we would get $f(x+y)=-f(x)$, contradiction again.

So we must have the two factors being reciprocals. Well now what? I'm stuck here. Clearly my approach is not just unprofessional, it's bad too. How can this thing be solved?

**EDIT:**

After considering @Yesit'sme's comment, I retried the problem and would like to present a solution. PLEASE DO TELL ME WHETHER IT IS CORRECT OR NOT. Here we go.

Since $x,y \in \mathbb R^+$, we may without restriction assume $x,y \neq 0$.

Now from given,

$\begin{align}
\big(1 + yf(x)\big)\big(1 − yf(x + y)\big) &= 1 \\
1 − yf(x + y)&= \frac{1}{1 + yf(x)} \\
1-\frac{1}{1 + yf(x)} &= yf(x + y) \\ 
\frac{1+yf(x)-1}{1 + yf(x)} &= yf(x + y) \\
\frac{f(x)}{1+yf(x)} &= f(x+y)= \frac{f(y)}{1+xf(y)} \tag 1 \label 1
\end{align}$

$\forall x,y \in \mathbb R^+$.

The last equation follow from symmetry (or plugging in $y+x$ into $f$).

Now by plugging in $y=1$ we see that,
$ f(x+1) =\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}<f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb R^+$.

The last inequality follows from the fact that,

$\begin{align} f(x)+1 &>1 \\ 
1 &>\frac{1}{f(x)+1} \\ 
f(x)&>\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1}=f(x+1) \end{align}$

As $f(x) \in \mathbb R^+$.

Thus $f(x)$ is in fact decreasing. We now define a new function $Q$ such that,

$f(x)=\frac{1}{Q(x)}$

where $Q$ is strictly increasing $\forall x$.

Plugging this into \eqref{1} we get,

$\begin{align} \frac{\frac{1}{Q(x)}}{1+\frac{y}{Q(x)}} &= \frac{\frac{1}{Q(y)}}{1+\frac{x}{Q(y)}} \\
\frac{1}{Q(x)+y} &= \frac{1}{Q(y)+x} \\ 
Q(x)+y &=Q(y)+x \\
Q(y)-y &=Q(x)-x=k \\ \end{align} $

Where $k \in \mathbb R$ is a constant. This gives,

$\begin{align}\frac{1}{f(x)} &= x+k \\
\therefore f(x) &= \frac{1}{x+k} \blacksquare. \\ \end{align} $

Plugging this into the original equation we see that the equation is satisfied and hence the solution is complete.

(I didn't show the checking part as typing out this much already took a boatload of time. Hope you understand. It does satisfy though, I have checked it by hand.)

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ works.

Comment: Yes silly me. That was infact one of my first thoughts after realising that functions of form $ax+b$ clearly won't make the cut. However i didn't do the computations full which lead me to believe it doesnt work lol.

Comment: $f(x + 1) < f(x)$ doesn't imply that $f$ is decreasing, but it doesn't matter because you never make use of $f$ being decreasing any way.

Comment: @Dylan, So you mean this would hv gotten a full score in like an actual USAMO? Maybe -1 for saying that f is decreasing?.

Comment: @AayamMathur It would depend on your presentation. The way you have written this up (which involved you thinking it through and typing it up), it's clear that the section about decreasing can be ignored without affecting the rest of the proof, and so it usually would not count against you, meaning you get the full 7. Having said that, in a competition setting where your work might be all over the place, and you might be penalized heavily if you had a statement like "Since $Q$ is strictly increasing, hence $Q(y) - y = Q(x) - x$", and so the solution could be worth 1.

Comment: It is (almost) always better to have a neatly written up version of your proof (and hopefully you'd catch errors/redundant parts like this). I've seen cases where the contestant had the correct steps, but was written on paper in the wrong order (reading from top to bottom), and the scoring changed a $7^-$ to a $0^+$. (As a simplified description, the correct proof is $ A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$, and the sequence on scratch paper was $ A, C, B$. The contestant knew $C$ was incomplete, and didn't realize $B$ would help fill in the gap.)

Comment: @CalvinLin Ohh i see. Thanks for the info i'll really keep the neatness in mind. Also could you if possible provide some more tips on how i could be better prepared to tackle the imo? What according to you separates the silver\bronze medalists from the perfect 42/42 scorers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all functions ${\rm f} :{ \mathbb R}_{+}\to{ \mathbb R}_{+}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674175/find-all-functions-rm-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x,y \in \mathbb R^+$, we may without restriction assume $x,y \neq 0$.

Now from given,

$ \begin{align} (1 + yf(x))(1 − yf(x + y)) &= 1 \\
1 − yf(x + y)&= \frac{1}{1 + yf(x)} \\
1-\frac{1}{1 + yf(x)} &= yf(x + y) \\ 
\frac{1+yf(x)-1}{1 + yf(x)} &= yf(x + y) \\
\frac{f(x)}{1+yf(x)} &= f(x+y)= \frac{f(y)}{1+xf(y)} \tag 1 \label {eqn1} \\ \end{align} $

$\forall x,y \in \mathbb R^+$.

The last equation follow from symmetry (or plugging in $y+x$ into $f$).

Since,
$f ( x + y ) = \frac { f ( x ) } { f ( x ) + y } = \frac 1 { \frac 1 { f ( x ) } + y }<\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=f(x)$

The inequality follows from the fact that,

$\begin{align} y &>0 \\ 
\frac{1}{f(x)}+y &>\frac{1}{f(x)} \\ 
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}} &> \frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}+y} \end{align}$

As $f(x) \in \mathbb R^+$.

Thus, $f(x)$ is in fact decreasing.

We now define a new function $Q$ such that,

$f(x)=\frac{1}{Q(x)}$

Since $f \neq 0$.

Plugging this into \eqref{eqn1} we get,

$\begin{align} \frac{\frac{1}{Q(x)}}{1+\frac{y}{Q(x)}} &= \frac{\frac{1}{Q(y)}}{1+\frac{x}{Q(y)}} \\
\frac{1}{Q(x)+y} &= \frac{1}{Q(y)+x} \\ 
Q(x)+y &=Q(y)+x \\
Q(y)-y &=Q(x)-x=k \\ \end{align} $

Where $k \in \mathbb R$ is a constant. This gives,

$\begin{align}\frac{1}{f(x)} &= x+k \\
\therefore f(x) &= \frac{1}{x+k} \blacksquare. \\ \end{align} $

Plugging this into the original equation we see that the equation is satisfied and hence the solution is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from two simple observations, your answer after the EDIT makes perfect sense.

One is that the constant $ k $ can't be an arbitrary real number, and must be nonnegative (which you may have implicitly taken into account, but haven't asserted explicitly). That's because if $ k < 0 $, then $ - k \in \mathbb R ^ + $, and thus we should have $ Q ( - k ) - ( - k ) = k $, or equivalently $ Q ( - k ) = 0 $, which can't happen as by definition, codomain of $ Q $ is $ \mathbb R ^ + $. Knowing $ k \ge 0 $, your claim that $ f ( x ) = \frac 1 { x + k } $ is a solution, works perfectly well.

The other one is the comment by @Dylan, which adresses your claim about $ f $ being decreasing. As the comment states, you haven't used the fact that $ f $ is decreasing, but I want to stress that you could prove that fact by changing your argument just a little bit. At that point, you know that $ f ( x + y ) = \frac { f ( x ) } { f ( x ) + y } = \frac 1 { \frac 1 { f ( x ) } + y } $. As $ y > 0 $, you have $ \frac 1 { f ( x ) } + y > \frac 1 { f ( x ) } $, and then $ f ( x + y ) = \frac 1 { \frac 1 { f ( x ) } + y } < \frac 1 { \frac 1 { f ( x ) } } = f ( x ) $, which proves what is desired.

I'd like to add another way of thinking, which is essentially your own argument, but may be useful in my opinion. You could observe from the beginning that $ 1 - y f ( x + y ) = \frac 1 { 1 + y f ( x ) } > 0 $, which shows that $ f ( x + y ) < \frac 1 y $. This means that for every $ x , y \in \mathbb R ^ + $ with $ x < y $ we must have $ f ( y ) < \frac 1 x $, or equivalently for every $ y \in \mathbb R ^ + $, $ f ( y ) \le \frac 1 y $, which in turn shows that letting $ k _ y = \frac 1 { f ( y ) } - y $, we must have $ k _ y \ge 0 $. Then you could rewrite $ f ( x + y ) = \frac 1 { \frac 1 { f ( x ) } + y } $ as $ f ( x + y ) = \frac 1 { \left( \frac 1 { f ( x ) } - x \right) + ( x + y ) } $, which simply means that for every $ x , y \in \mathbb R ^ + $ with $ x < y $, we have $ f ( y ) = \frac 1 { y + k _ x } $. This means that for every $ x , y \in \mathbb R ^ + $, if we choose $ z $ so that $ z > \max ( x , y ) $, we must have $ \frac 1 { z + k _ x } = f ( z ) = \frac 1 { z + k _ y } $, which proves that $ k _ x = k _ y $, so we could simply use a single nonnegative constant $ k $, and we're done.

Comment: Lol at first id written $R^+$ for k but then i just thought lemme replace k with -k and  see if the functional equation is satisfied. This reminds me of the pathological solutions mentioned in evan chan's handouts. What satisfies the equation may or may not be right as it may not fit the other criteria, domain , codomain in this case. I should have realised that had k been a negative integer such that $|x|<|k|$ the output of $f$ would infact have been negative which isn't allowed. Thanks for that now ill always check stuff with the other conditions as well and not just the equation.

Comment: Also then, was saying that Q is strictly increasing, unnecessary? I mean my personal thought was if i cud show f is decreasing then i cud simply define a new function as its reciprocal. So it turns out that m actually dumb. I didn't need to write anything related to increasing or decreasing isn't it? Coz f can't be 0 then we basically have no problem. Isnt it? So without writing anything related to f or Q being increasing or decreasing i cud have just defined Q without any loopholes?

Comment: That's right. The only thing necessary for defining $ Q $ on $ \mathbb R ^ + $ is that $ f $ is nonzero everywhere, so that $ \frac 1 { f ( x ) } $ makes sense for every $ x $. That's true since $ f $ only takes nonzero values, and has nothing to do with being decreasing.

Comment: Ohhh. Thanks a lot my dude. You kinda opened my eyes lol and made me more aware for the future. $<3$. Also now ig ill just copy paste my solution with the changes and accept it later so that the question has an accepted answer. Btw, on a scale of 1-10,how much would you rate my solution? On the basis of how it was done and procedure ofc.